# How to fix the page order when printing a PDF on both sides

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, hp-officejet

I have opened a PDF with Adobe Reader and printed it on both sides of the paper. The printer is an HP Officejet Pro 251dw. The document is printed cleanly, but the pages come out of the printer in the wrong order and I have to turn all the sheets by hand.

Expected page order when the sheets come out of the printer: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

Received page order: 2, 1, 4, 3, etc.

Is there a setting in Adobe Reader that I need to change for this purpose?

Comment: I do this routinely with Adobe. Does your printer have double sided capability?  and is it working correctly?

Comment: @John yes it does, otherwise I wouldn't be able to print double-side.

Comment: Strange.  Try reinstalling Adobe to see if that helps. I have an HP8610 printer and it has properly double sided with Office and Adobe for years.